# WHERE clause is not filtering on LESS THAN and GREATER THAN or BETWEEN

Tags: sql-server, query, select

I am trying to select MTR values that are between the values of 0 and 4. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
DATEDIFF(M, TheDate, TheOtherDate) AS MTR FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyID = 2074163
AND MTR >= 0  OR MTR <= 4
```

Returns results that contain values inside and outside of the bounds of MTR being between 1 and 4. (from -3 to 75)

Alternately

```
SELECT 
DATEDIFF(M, TheDate, TheOtherDate) AS MTR FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyID = 2074163
and MTR BETWEEN 0 AND 4
```

Is also returning results that are 0, -2, -3, and -4 - but nothing higher than 0 and less than 4 (except for the entries that are 0)

Comment: Both queries are invalid, unless there is an `MTR` column in the table.

Comment: On a, perhaps, slightly irrelevant note, make sure your `TheDate` value is not greater than `TheOtherDate` if you expect to receive non-negative results. I.e., `DATEDIFF(M, '2012-02-20', '2012-05-15')` evaluates to `3`, but if you swap the dates, you'll get `-3`.

Comment: The reason why you're getting values less than 0 is because of the OR in your WHERE clause, this should've been AND. Max's query below will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for this would be:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(M, TheDate, TheOtherDate) AS MTR 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyID = 2074163 AND (
    DATEDIFF(M, TheDate, TheOtherDate) >= 0 AND
    DATEDIFF(M, TheDate, TheOtherDate) <= 4
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Ypercube's comment is relevant.  The reference to `MTR` in your `WHERE` clause should be flagged as invalid, according to the standard.  But apart from that, which value of `MTR` do you think will ever make that **`OR`** evaluate to **`false`** ?